# Can move object from vector A to vector B, but not from B to A?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class which has a vector of objects. The objects in question have deleted copy constructors and copy assignment operators, and thus they have a move constructor and move assignment operator to allow them to be used with vectors. This class that holds the objects has append and extract methods which allow objects to be appended to the class' object vector from a buffer or extracted from the class' object vector to a buffer.

The object definition looks like this:

```
struct MyObject
{
    int width_ = 0;
    int height_ = 0;
    //etc...

    stImage() = default; 

    stImage(int width, int height, ...)
    {
        width_ = width;
        height_ = height;
        //etc...
    }

    stImage(const stImage& rhs) = delete;

    stImage& operator= (const stImage & rhs) = delete;

    stImage(stImage&& rhs) : width_(0), height_(0), ...
    {
        *this = std::move(rhs);
    }

    stImage& operator=(stImage&& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            width_ = rhs.width_;
            height_ = rhs.height_;
            //etc...

            rhs.width_ = 0;
            rhs.height_ = 0;
            //etc...
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The append methods compile:

```
void MyClass::append(MyObject * buffer)
{
    data_.push_back(std::move(*buffer));
}

void MyClass::append(Vector<MyObject> * buffer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (*buffer).size(); i++) 
    {
        data_.push_back(std::move((*buffer)[i]));
    }
 }
```

However, the extract method does not:

```
void MyClass::extract(it8 start, Length length, Vector<MyObject> * buffer) const
{
    for (it8 i = start; i < (start + length); i++) 
    {
        (*buffer).push_back(std::move(data_[i]));
    }
}
```

The error given is "C2280 'MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject &)': attempting to reference a deleted function"

I can't see why these two operations are functionally any different from each other. Any insight into why extract fails and append does not would be appreciated, and a way to make extract work would be even more so.

(Note: Vector here is a custom implementation of std::vector because Reasons, but as far as I'm aware, they function the same. If this is potentially the issue, and std::vector would be fine with append/extract as they stand, I guess I'll see if using it would be OK.)

Comment: What is the compiler output?

Comment: You're doing this from a `const` method ? Interesting... If the method is const, then so shall be the chosen `operator[]` for `data_` would it not?

Comment: @Aeonos C2280 'MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: `extract` is a const member function and in const member function every reference to member variables are `const`s. When you access to `data_[i]` the returning data type is `const MyObject&`. So you are pushing a const object to vector that will call this overload `push_back(const T&)`.

Comment: ... which means a copy-construction attempt (that obviously failed).

Comment: in std::vector::push_back  copies object, and std::vector::emplace_back moves object, in your custom implementation push_back moves or copies, or there are overloaded versions that take T, T&, T&& ? And if it do same as std::vector (copies) here is your error; (by the way, if it was std::vector, your use of std::move would be pointless, it still will use copy constructor , not move constructor)

Comment: Ah, of course, it was using 'const' that was the issue. I missed that. Thank you all for your help!
@MRB, if you wanted to post that as an answer, I'd accept it - you've given the fullest explanation here.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I don't think your comments on std::vector are quite right; [push_back copies or moves](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) and my use of std::move with push_back is directly from [this reference using push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Comment: @AndrewKashpur [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) has an rval-ref overload for move semantics. It doesn't always copy. [It just needs to be setup properly](http://ideone.com/5QX9pe) (which the posted code didn't in the extract case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extract` is a const member function and in const member function every reference to member variables are consts. When you access to `data_[i]` the returning data type is `const MyObject&`.

[`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just cast it's input to a r-value reference and in your case the return type of `std::move` is `const MyObject&&`, but because object has `const` qualifier the chosen overload for `push_back` will be `push_back(const T&)`.

You can use `const_cast` to remove `const` from `data_`, But it's not the best solution. Also `mutable` keyword can be used, but the best solution is to declare your function as non-const function because it's modifying object internal state.

Answer (score 0):

Constness, I guess.
'extract' removes from data_, so can not be const.